# Why get object twice?

Tags: django, django-class-based-views

This code is from here (http://gswd-a-crash-course-pycon-2014.readthedocs.org/en/latest/talksmodel.html). . .In the TalkListRemoveTalkView, he overrides get_object and gets the specific Talk. Then he overrides the get method, and again retrieves the object. . .

My question is, if he gets the object we need in the get_object method, why do we need to again call get_object in the get method?

Thinking out loud, does the get method pull in the kwargs from the URL for the Talk and TalkList, then pass them to the get_object method for the query? Or do I have this completely wrong? Thanks in advance.

```
class TalkListRemoveTalkView(views.LoginRequiredView, RedirectView):
    model = Talk

    def get_redirect_url(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.talklist.get_absolute_url()

    def get_object(self, pk, talklist_pk):
        try:
            talk = self.model.objects.get(
                pk=pk,
                talk_list_id=talklist_pk,
                talk_list__user=self.request.user
            )
        except Talk.DoesNotExist:
            raise Http404
        else:
            return talk

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object(kwargs.get('pk'),
                                      kwargs.get('talklist_pk'))
        self.talklist = self.object.talk_list
        self.object.delete()
        return super(TalkListRemoveTalkView, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He's not doing it twice. The call to `get_object` in the `get` method is the only time that method is called. There's no reference to it outside that call, and this view does not inherit from any other views that would call it elsewhere.

Note though that this code is bad for other reasons; in particular, you must never do a destructive action like a delete in a GET call, those should always be done on POST.

Comment: Thanks, Daniel .I see, so he just puts the query in get_object then calls it in the get method and passes in the kwargs.?